# Add cross account delegation to existing hosted zone

Tags: amazon-route53, aws-cdk

I can create a new hosted zone with cross account delegation like this

```typescript
const parentZone = new route53.PublicHostedZone(this, 'HostedZone', {
  zoneName: 'someexample.com',
  crossAccountZoneDelegationPrincipal: new iam.AccountPrincipal('12345678901'),
  crossAccountZoneDelegationRoleName: 'MyDelegationRole',
});
```

This is pretty straightforward. But what if hosted zone already exist

```typescript
const parentHostedZone = route53.PublicHostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'HostedZone', {
    domainName: 'someexample.com',
})
```

How to add delegation to this zone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What those props do is just create a role that can be assumed in another account and used for adding records to the parent zone.

The code is [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/443fb2a7b55f24087e8c638f48c4d8803b629244/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-route53/lib/hosted-zone.ts#L278:L298):

```typescript
if (props.crossAccountZoneDelegationPrincipal) {
  this.crossAccountZoneDelegationRole = new iam.Role(this, 'CrossAccountZoneDelegationRole', {
    roleName: props.crossAccountZoneDelegationRoleName,
    assumedBy: props.crossAccountZoneDelegationPrincipal,
    inlinePolicies: {
      delegation: new iam.PolicyDocument({
        statements: [
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            actions: ['route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets'],
            resources: [this.hostedZoneArn],
          }),
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            actions: ['route53:ListHostedZonesByName'],
            resources: ['*'],
          }),
        ],
      }),
    },
  });
}
```

You can simply create this role and it will achieve the same thing.

It would look like this:

```typescript
const crossAccountZoneDelegationRole = new iam.Role(this, 'CrossAccountZoneDelegationRole', {
    roleName: 'MyDelegationRole',
    assumedBy: new iam.AccountPrincipal('12345678901'),
    inlinePolicies: {
      delegation: new iam.PolicyDocument({
        statements: [
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            actions: ['route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets'],
            resources: [parentZone.hostedZoneArn],
          }),
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            actions: ['route53:ListHostedZonesByName'],
            resources: ['*'],
          }),
        ],
      }),
    },
  });
```

Then, in another account, you just do the usual thing. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53-readme.html):

```typescript
// import the delegation role by constructing the roleArn
const delegationRoleArn = Stack.of(this).formatArn({
  region: '', // IAM is global in each partition
  service: 'iam',
  account: 'parent-account-id',
  resource: 'role',
  resourceName: 'MyDelegationRole',
});
const delegationRole = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'DelegationRole', delegationRoleArn);

// create the record
new route53.CrossAccountZoneDelegationRecord(this, 'delegate', {
  delegatedZone: subZone,
  parentHostedZoneName: 'someexample.com', // or you can use parentHostedZoneId
  delegationRole,
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I kinda figured this was about a role, just wasn't sure what permissions are needed and what would be the best way to create it. This really helps. The only drawback I see - it will have to be 2 separate stacks, one to create the role in parent account, another to actually use the role in child account. Is there a way to do this in one - e.g. like in terraform to create resource and pass provider as parameter?

Comment: No, a single stack can only create resources in a single environment (unless it's a nested stack that contains other stacks).